# How are loops within a process synthesized in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm working on the implementation of a FIR filter in VHDL and need some advice regarding when to use and not to use process statements. Part of the code is presented below. Specifically, I'm wodering how the `resetCoeffs` loop will synthesize. Will it be a sequential reset, and so be very inefficeint in both speed and area I assume, or will it be done in parallel? If the former is the case, how would I go about writing it so that is can be a parallel reset.

```
process (clk) is begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst = '1' then
            -- Reset pointer
            ptr <= (others => '0');

            -- Reset coefficients
            resetCoeffs: for i in 0 to ORDER - 1 loop
                coeffs(i) <= (others => '0');
            end loop;
        else
            -- Increment pointer
            ptr <= ptr + 1;

            -- Fetch input value
            vals( to_integer(ptr) ) <= ival;

            -- Write coefficient
            if coeff_wen = '1' then
                coeffs( to_integer(ptr) ) <= ival;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be parallel. It basically has to be since the whole loop (everything in the process, really) has to operate in a single clock cycle in hardware.

I'm curious, though. Since you've made the effort to write out the whole process, why not just synthesize it with your favorite synthesizer?  That's what I did, to check my answer.

Comment: I haven't really got that far as to synthesize things. I'm currently just simulating with ghdl (which has no synthesizer).

Answer (score 2):

Once a process begin execution (because of a change in one of the signals in its sensitivity list) it must run until it suspends, either by reaching the end, or reaching a `wait` statement.

Because of this defined behaviour, loops will "execute" all their code until they exit before time is allowed to move on in the simulator.  The synthesiser will therefore create the same behaviour by unrolling all the loop and making sure it "all happens at once" (or at least within the clock tick for a clocked process like yours).